# Using a DynamoDb table from another account in Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

Is it possible to use a dynamodb table from another AWS Account in Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) ?
I've found a link about prerequisites below which says they have to be in the same account:
http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB_PreRequisites.html

But i am not sure if it is still valid. Is there any other way?

Thanks.